# How to log error messages with Flask and foreman (heroku)?

Tags: python, heroku, flask, error-logging, foreman

I am working with Flask and Foreman for the Heroku hosting. I start my local server typing `foreman start`. My issue is that I want to see the log error messages that my code produces but I haven't found the right way to do it.

I tried with some code that I found in the Flask documentation like this, but it doesn't work either:

```
import logging
from FileHandler import FileHandler
file_handler = FileHandler("log.txt")
file_handler.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
app.logger.addHandler(file_handler)
```

Any idea how to be able to read de error messages when running Flask with `foreman start`?

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar problem - in the end the issue wasn't with Foreman, but with using a newer version of Gunicorn where console logging was disabled by default (http://gunicorn-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html#why-i-don-t-see-any-logs-in-the-console).

Changing my procfile from:

```
web: gunicorn app:app
```

to

```
web: gunicorn --log-file=- app:app
```

solved the issue for me.

Comment: MY GOD (or GORD, should I say?) - I have been looking for two days for this answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Heroku and Foreman expect your logs to go to `stdout` or `stderr`, not to a file. See [the Heroku documentation on logging](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging#writing-to-your-log).

For a Python app you can use the [logging.StreamHandler](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.StreamHandler) class, which logs to `stderr` by default.